# Showing that a harmonic function is 0

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> Let u(x) a harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such as:
>    \begin{equation}
>  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u(x)|dx =K< \infty
>  \end{equation}
>    Show thtat $u(x)=0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Using the property of volumetric mean I get that, for a sphere $B(a,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the value of $u(a)$ is:
\begin{equation}
u(a)=\frac{1}{\omega_nr^{n-1}}\int\limits_{B(a,r)}u(x)dx
\end{equation}

By the fact that $u(a)\leq |u(a)|$ we get the following inequalities
\begin{equation}
u(a)\leq |u(a)|=\bigg|\frac{1}{\omega_nr^{n-1}}\int\limits_{B(a,r)}u(x)dx\bigg|\leq \frac{1}{\omega_nr^{n-1}}\int\limits_{B(a,r)}|u(x)|dx\leq \frac{1}{\omega_nr^{n-1}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u(x)|dx= \frac{1}{\omega_nr^{n-1}}K
\end{equation}

As $r\to \infty $ we get that $|u(a)|\leq K\lim\limits_{r \to \infty} \frac{1}{\omega_nr^{n-1}}=0 $.

So $|u(a)|\leq 0\implies |u(a)|= 0 \implies u(a)=0$.

Since $a$ is arbitrary we get that
  \begin{equation}
    u(x)=0 , \ \ \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n
  \end{equation}

I'm not so secure that this argumentation is valid. If it is wrong can anybody tell me where?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: basically correct, just some small things - you don't need to use $u(a) \le |u(a)|$, just $0\le |u(a)| \le f(r)\to  0$ is enough, and are you using the spherical or volume average, shouldn't $|B(a,r)|\sim r^n$ instead of $r^{n-1}$